# How to send onClick JavaScript email if I already have the serverside code for it?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an HTML file where I want to send an email when people click on links.

I already have the server-side code and a URL which will generate the email:

```
http://www.url.com/send_email_mobile.php?subject=x&title=y
```

But I am not sure if I need to make an ajax call in an onClick event or is there a better way? I last used ajax like 10 years ago.

What's the simples way to hit that URL without slowing down the user from landing on the url where they actually clicked?

Comment: you better use ajax or jquery ajax otherwise you will have a page reload on completing the post request if you use normal html form post

Comment: other hack is to  not use backend code and use `mailto:` link so that you can just invoke a mailer configured on your pc ( this does not work if the default mailer is not configured ) try this : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_address.asp

Comment: What are actually trying to achieve here? Do you want to send the email when the user clicks on the link? Or after some other kind of action? Please clarify.

Comment: `fetch("the url")` ...

Comment: @BenM yes exactly, I want to know when they click and where.

Comment: @JonasWilms how would that work in the code? Where does that go?

Answer (score 1):

Obviously you will have to make an ajax call since it is client side and you need to contact the server so you'll need to make a request to the server using ajax.

Comment: Thanks, how do I do that from the onClick?

Comment: After the onClick event occurs obviously you'll be calling a function. Inside that function you need to make an ajax request to your server. You can try using axios also, It's same as ajax with some more functionality and better user understanding experience.
https://github.com/axios/axios.
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
function clicked(url) {
  // your server call
  fetch('http://www.url.com/send_email_mobile.php?subject=x&title=y%27')
    .then(function(response) {
      // response from server
      console.log(response.text()); // to print/use the response in text or response.json() if the response is in json.

      // If you want to wait for the mail request to finish and then open the url in same tab:
      // window.location.href = url;
    });
  // If you don't want to wait for the mail request to finish and open the url in new tab instantly.
  window.open(url)
}
```

Demo:

```js
function clicked(url) {
  // your server call
  fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(json => console.log(json))
  // open the link in new tab
  window.open(url)
}
```

```html
<a onclick="clicked('https://stackoverflow.com/')">Click me to go to stackoverflow!</a>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7sy45tc6/) where link actually opens in new tab.

Comment: Thank you! I am not too comfortable with JavaScript - would it be possible to add actual code instead of pseudocode? I am assuming these are pseudocode:     .then(response => response.json()).then(json => console.log(json))

Comment: .then part is where you get the response from the url. Without waiting in the main function(this is called a promise). If you just need to hit the url and don't want to do anything on the response, you can remove it.

Comment: what if I don't use the fetch at all and just open the url? I am not sure which part of your code is necessary and not, and is this pseudocode since there are no semicolons at the end of lines? What else is an approximation?

Comment: Also what is this call and url? fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')

Comment: Yes, jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1 is just a dummy url that returns some [json](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/). So in fetch you'll use your backend url to trigger mail. So do fetch('http://www.url.com/send_email_mobile.php?subject=x&title=y')

Comment: and fetch will return whatever the server sends back in the then function. [This](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/03/introduction-to-fetch) should help in understanding fetch more.